# GoogleTokenResponse.getIdToken() returns null

Tags: google-oauth

Our server OAuth validation via Google has started throwing NullPointerException within GoogleTokenResponse.parseIdToken():

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
at com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature$Parser.parse(JsonWebSignature.java:462)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.parse(GoogleIdToken.java:57)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse.parseIdToken(GoogleTokenResponse.java:106)
```

This is new behavior that started today. There was no change to our server code (it has worked for months). The problem occurs only with credentials from one Android device -- I have another that works fine. Refreshing the client's server access token does not solve the problem.

The GoogleTokenResponse is being created by GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(), that call succeeds and when I log the GoogleTokenResponse it looks valid:

{"access_token":"ya29.mwJvM...","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer"}

---

UPDATE: tested some more and found tokenResponse.getIdToken() is returning null, so I assume that's what's causing the NPE when I call parseIdToken().

What would cause getIdToken() to return null when GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest() apparently succeeded and there is an access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final resolution: this issue appears to be triggered intermittently  by the Google Play Services update in early 2016 to anonymize PlayerID. We were able to fix our problems by changing our server validation of the access token to a newer method instead of relying on the older getIdToken()/parseIdToken() methods. See the last UPDATE below for details

---

After two days the Android device with this failure mysteriously started to work again. So the cause may be a transient error in the client's Google Play Services state which self-corrected. The fix occurred after a device reboot.

However I'm not certain that was the cause. There are also Play Services changes rolling out to enable authentication without exposing the G+ user ID -- another explanation is the server was not being given scope to retrieve the ID. (If that was the cause, then again the fix must have been deployed by Google as we have not changed anything)

We'll continue to monitor it, if anyone else runs into this add a comment please.

---

4/19/16 This problem has occurred on a different device. I am wondering if this is related to the Google Play auth changes described here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html?m=1

That explanation is a bit sparse but it does say "The user_id returned by token info may no longer be present with the new model. And even if it is present, the value won’t be the same as the new player ID"

In this case the problem occurred after

- Device had previously authorized with Google Play Services in the old G+-style
- App data was cleared so re-auth was necessary
- During re-auth GPS prompted for the new GPS-only player ID (not real name), which makes me wonder if it switched that device to the new non-G+ ID
- Then server calls to tokenResponse.getIdToken() returned null

I'm not yet sure what's happening but researching two areas of concern:

1) Although the Google docs referenced above say "existing players ... will continue to get their Google+ ID" I'm wondering if this is managed per-client. That would be a big problem because we use that ID to store cloud state for a user across devices, so if a user who originally set up their account before the new player ID then installed the app on a second device, they could sign in with gplay but the two accounts would not match

2) If this is the cause, then either our server code fails to work with the new non-G+ player ID, or there is a google back-end bug when a device transitions between the two. This is still confusing though because our prior problem did self-correct after a couple of days, which implies the server code is fine -- but I'm sure hoping the alternate explanation of a bug with google back-end auth is wrong!

--- UPDATE

I think the issue is related to the new GPS anonymized PlayerID changes. It has been hard to debug because it appears that Google's legacy server auth flow, which requires a non-null GoogleTokenResponse.getIdToken(), fails for a newly created GPS PlayerID, but after 12-24 h the problem seems to self-correct and the legacy Google auth calls begin to succeed including returning a non-null getIdToken().

However I tried implementing the new PlayerID flow in the Step 7 of the google info page above which converts the access token (generated from a server auth code) to a Player ID via www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications//verify/

This code successfully retrieves a Player ID from the accessToken even when getToken() returns null:

```
// URL: www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/<app_id>/verify/
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/" + GPlayServicesAppId + "/verify/");

HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);
httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    ...
}
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
String responseJson = (read contents of reader)

// Example response: { "kind": "games#applicationVerifyResponse", "player_id": "11520..."}
```

I ran some tests, far as I can tell the new method works in all cases where the older G+ getToken() method works as well as fixing the cases where it doesn't, so I believe we can just switch to the new method in the code snippet above and hopefully that will be reliable.

Comment: I have also recently begun to get this response when previously the code was working.  Any updates?

Comment: The problem never re-occurred for us, so all I learned is that it was temporary, affected a single device, and the fix did not require changing code. My best guess is it was a gplay bug. If you're getting the problem on only a specific device you could try clearing cached data for gplay services -- no idea if it will help, but if that fixes it then it's pretty definitely a gplay problem

Comment: I also use the new playerID flow that you point to in your update and it always works for me.